# Appending a single character from one array to another

Tags: c

This is one of those nights when C is just killing me. How do I read an array one character at a time and append that character onto the end of another array?

```
            bzero(message, BUFFSIZE);  // 1024 bytes
            strcpy(message, "your_file|");

            for (j=0; j<bytes_read; ++j) {
                fprintf(stdout, "%c", buffer[j]);
                strcat(message, buffer[j]);  //<--THIS FAILS!!! WHY!!!!
            }

            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", message);
```

As a professor once told me "C doesn't like you." Well, tonight I think C is mad at me.

Comment: One character at a time is easy. `for(i = 0; i < ARR_LEN; ++i) {dest[i] = src[i];}`

Comment: Tried that earlier, or so I thought. It works now. This is not my night...  Thank you!

Comment: Well, `strcat` takes two null-terminated strings as arguments and appends one to the other. If I am correct in assuming that `buffer` is a `char*` or a `char[]`, then `buffer[j] ` is a `char`, not a string, and therefore cannot be used as an argument to `strcat`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31214337/694576

Answer (score 1):

[`strcat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) expects second argument to be `const char *` (C string), while you're giving it a `char`.

You could convert your `char` into C string, i.e. create an array

```
char append[] = { buffer[j], '\0' }`
```

or append a single character each time and at the very end append null-byte:

```
        bzero(message, BUFFSIZE);  // 1024 bytes
        strcpy(message, "your_file|");
        size_t len = strlen(message);

        for (j=0; j<bytes_read; ++j) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%c", buffer[j]);
            message[len++] = buffer[j];
        }

        message[len] = '\0';

        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", message);
```