# trying to append a character to a character array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to append the character 't' to a character array having the value of "hello", I'm determining the array size, creating a new array that is 1 character bigger, assigning the new char and '\0' as the final two characters.
I keep getting the old value(hello) printed out. thanks

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void append(char * string,char ch)
{
  int size;
  for (size=0;size<255;size++)
  {
    if (string[size]=='\0')
      break;
  }
  char temp[size+2];
  strcpy(temp,string);
  temp[size+1]='t';
  temp[size+2]='\0';
  printf("the test string is: %s\n",temp);
}

int main()
{
  char test[]="hello";
  append(&test,'t');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd do better to use `strnlen()` — or `strlen()` — than writing out the loop longhand as you do.

Comment: Indexing of arrays in C is `0`-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your function call is wrong. It should be

```
append(test,'t');  // When an argument to a function, array decay to pointer to its first element.
```

Then, you have to remove the `'\0'` from the previous string otherwise you will get the same string. Its because after appending  the character `ch`, the new string will look like

```
"hello\0t\0"
```

Notice the `'\0'` before `t`. `printf` will stop at that null character.

You can overwrite that `'\0'` character with the character `'t'` as

```
temp[size] = ch;
temp[size+1] = '\0';
```

---

**Note:** Your program invokes undefined behavior because of out of bound access of array `temp` in statement

```
 temp[size+2]='\0';
```

Comment: When an empty string is passed `size` from the OP function will be `0` since it is the index of the terminator, so the `temp[size-1] = ch;` is incorrect (even though I upvoted).

Answer (score 2):

A valid function can look the following way

```
void append( const char *string, char ch )
{
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( string[size] ) ++size;

    char temp[size+2];

    strcpy( temp, string );

    temp[size++] = ch;
    temp[size++] ='\0';

    printf( "the test string is: %s\n", temp );
}
```

And it has to be called like

```
append( test, 't' );
```

Answer (score 1):

As the loop is breaking whenever `string[size]=='\0'`, an then string is copied to `temp`, `temp[size]` is `\0` as well and it is never overwritten, because the next character assigned is at `size+1`. So your temp is always terminated at `size`. At the end `temp` is `"hello\0t\0"`

Answer (score 0):

You find but never overwrite the first null character.